Axis.text not angling the x val labels though no error arises
I am trying to angle values within a "treatment" variable. There are ten treatments and I wanted to relabel them to names and then angle them so they do not overlap. When I do the standard axis.text code, it runs but does not angle in the values on the x axis in actual graph. I cannot figure out my problem.
ggplot(summary_stats, aes(x = as.factor(treatment_num), y = mean, ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci, 
                          color = ifelse(treatment_num %% 2 == 0, "Low", "High"))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "Regions", y = "DV: Policy Support", 
       title = "Difference in Means Between Treatments on Policy Support (Among All)") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:10, labels = c(
    "1" = "E High 1", "2" = "E Low", 
    "3" = "A High", "4" = "A Low", "5" = "ME High", 
    "6" = "ME Low", "7" = "LA High", 
    "8" = "LA Low", "9" = "AA High", "10" = "AA Low")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('High' = '#67a9cf', 'Low' = '#DF536B'), 
                     labels = c('High', 'Low'), 
                     guide = guide_legend(title = '')) +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "transparent")) +
  theme_bw()

I have also tried axis.ticks, axis.ticks.x, etc....
I am not sure if it is a problem on my end, but when I do this same code for other graphs, it works. I think it is totally ignoring that line of code, but why?

Welcome to SO! You have to put your adjustments via theme() after theme_bw(), i.e. do ... + theme_bw() + theme(...). For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

^ The reason for this is that ggplots will have default settings, and running the function theme(.....) will change the ones you specify, while running a theme function like theme_bw() will change a whole bunch of settings to the ones in that theme, likely overwriting any settings made up to that point.
